# Combining feature sets extracted from multiple models

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

I have extracted features from a large set of training and test images using Sklearn and Caffe. To perform the feature extraction, I used 3 different pre-trained convnets from Caffe Model Zoo.

Using any of the 3 sets of features, I can train an SVM which is about 80% accurate on the test data. But what is the best way to leverage the power of all 3 sets of features?

I have tried simply averaging the results of 3 separate SVMs together (averaging the probability predictions for each label), but it yielded no improvement over single models.

Would it help to concatenate the feature sets together into one large set and use that for training an SVM (or other)?

Note that the data set is multiclass multilabel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the good way to combine features. 
In machine learning we use ensemble techniques. Ensemble techniques: bagging, boosting, stacking and hierarchy. 
From my experience I like to work with either boosting or stacking.
Boosting is a greedy learning strategy that keeps changing the distribution of the data as well as the used feature to train each base learner so the coming base learner will focus on difficult samples.
Read about viola jones adaboost classifier.
If you have severe data imbalance problem read about SMOTEBoost algorithm

Comment: Thanks. Can ensemble techniques be used with multilabel data in sklearn?

Comment: Yes it can just search to find the best method that works with you.  Multi-label itself is still under research.  I am sorry I do not know a bout this package

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the following solution , but when using just the TFIDF + BOW features it gaves Accuracy: 0.899029126214 
when i have added the lexical features to them the Accuracy: 0.7747572815533981
i have used the featurunion to union the same features matrix (TFIDF + bow ) then i used the h.stack to stack the featureunion.vector + the lexical vecotor , the code as following :

```
# average number of words per sentence

    fvs_lexical[e, 0] = words_per_sentence.mean()
    # sentence length variation
    fvs_lexical[e, 1] = words_per_sentence.std()
    # Lexical diversity
    fvs_lexical[e, 2] = len(vocab) / float(len(words))
# apply whitening to decorrelate the features
fvs_lexical = whiten(fvs_lexical)
#bag of wrods features
bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=2, max_features=1000, stop_words='english') 
#tfidf 
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=2, max_features=1000, stop_words='english') 
#vectorizer and fitting for the unified features 
vectorizer = FeatureUnion([  ("baw", bow_vectorizer),("tfidf", tfidf_vectorizer)
fvs_lexical_vector = CountVectorizer(fvs_lexical)
x1 =vectorizer.fit_transform (train['text'].values.astype('U'))
x2 =fvs_lexical_vector.fit_transform (train['text'].values.astype('U'))
x= scipy.sparse.hstack((x2,x3),format='csr')
y = np.asarray(train['label'].values.astype('U'))
```

then i have run the logistic regression